# On my Windows 11 laptop, I've found a local user account that is called "EmergencyAdmin". Is this safe?

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts, administrator

I've noticed a local user account with administrator privileges called "EmergencyAdmin" on my laptop. Login data (via Belarc Advisor) indicates it is being accessed once per week. Web searches reveal almost nothing about EmergencyAdmin other than Microsoft Sentinel, which I do not use (nor do I use the MS cloud or Microsoft 360). What is the deal with EmergencyAdmin? Is it safe?

Comment: This is likely just the built-in Administrator account that by default is disabled and has simply been renamed. Have you asked your IT Administrator if the that is indeed the case?

Comment: Is your computer joined to a domain ?

Comment: Is this a business computer, or a personal computer?